# Tracker Algorithms in Open cv install

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror, tracker

Hello ı tried to use tracker algorithms but ı couldn't use also ı tried to install API's

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

and here is my code

```py
import cv2
def ask_for_tracker():
   print("Welcome! What Tracker API would you like to use?")
   print("Enter 0 for BOOSTING: ")
   print("Enter 1 for MIL: ")
   print("Enter 2 for KCF: ")
   print("Enter 3 for TLD: ")
   print("Enter 4 for MEDIANFLOW: ")
   choice = input("Please select your tracker: ")

   if choice == '0':
       tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
   if choice == '1':
       tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
   if choice == '2':
       tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
   if choice == '3':
       tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
   if choice == '4':
       tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()

   return tracker
tracker = ask_for_tracker()
```

here is my error thanks for help

[image]

Comment: There were significant changes in the tracker API somewhere around release 4.5.1 (late 2020). You seem to have used (outdated) documentation that doesn't match the version of OpenCV you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `opencv-contrib-python` library has been updated. Here's how your code should look like according to the [updated OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d04/namespacecv_1_1legacy.html):

```
import cv2
def ask_for_tracker():
    print("Welcome! What Tracker API would you like to use?")
    print("Enter 0 for BOOSTING: ")
    print("Enter 1 for MIL: ")
    print("Enter 2 for KCF: ")
    print("Enter 3 for TLD: ")
    print("Enter 4 for MEDIANFLOW: ")
    choice = input("Please select your tracker: ")

    if choice == '0':
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerBoosting_create()
    if choice == '1':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
    if choice == '2':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    if choice == '3':
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerTLD_create()
    if choice == '4':
        tracker = cv2.legacy_TrackerMedianFlow()
    return tracker

tracker = ask_for_tracker()
```

I tested this code for every choice with the latest `opencv-contrib-python` version: 4.8.0.76. Just do `pip install -U opencv-contrib-python`

Here's the code I tested for every tracker:

```
import cv2
def ask_for_tracker(choice):
    print("Choice: ",choice)
    if choice == '0':
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerBoosting_create()
    if choice == '1':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
    if choice == '2':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    if choice == '3':
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerTLD_create()
    if choice == '4':
        tracker = cv2.legacy_TrackerMedianFlow()
    return tracker
for i in range(5):
    tracker = ask_for_tracker(str(i))
    print(tracker)
```

Output:

```
Choice:  0
< cv2.legacy.TrackerBoosting 0x7f3eb2ee2f10>
Choice:  1
< cv2.TrackerMIL 0x7f3eb2ee2e70>
Choice:  2
< cv2.TrackerKCF 0x7f3eb2ee2f10>
Choice:  3
< cv2.legacy.TrackerTLD 0x7f3eb2ee2e70>
Choice:  4
< cv2.legacy.TrackerMedianFlow 0x7f3eb2ee2f10>
```

##### Hope it helps!